# Selected entries not being removed properly

Tags: javascript

I'm making a simple to-do list, where a user adds entries and can remove them as well.

Here's where i am facing a problem. If i am selecting multiple entries for removal, only one is being removed. However, if i select the first and the third entries or the second or fourth entries, or multiple entries, sometimes they are being removed. How can i address this issue to remove all selected entries?

Problem is in the last section (Remove items from List)

```
let displayarea = document.createElement("div")
displayarea.className = "tasklistdisplay";
let emptylist = document.createElement("ul")
emptylist.className = "tasklist";
let textbox = document.createElement("input");
let addbutton = document.createElement("button");
let removebutton = document.createElement("button");

//---------------------------Adding all the initalized elements to HTML Markup------------------------------------------------------------//
displayarea.appendChild(emptylist);
document.body.appendChild(textbox);
document.body.appendChild(addbutton);
document.body.appendChild(removebutton);
document.body.appendChild(displayarea);

//--------------------- Set Style Attributes of initalized elements-------------------------------------------//
addbutton.innerText = "Add to List!";
addbutton.setAttribute("style", "width:200px; height:30px;");
removebutton.innerText = "Remove from List!";
removebutton.setAttribute("style", "width:200px; height:30px;");

//--------------------------------Add Item to list-------------------------------------------//
function createlistitem() {
  let listdiv = document.createElement('div');
  listdiv.className = "mahadiv";
  let checkbox = document.createElement('input');
  checkbox.type = "checkbox";
  checkbox.value = 1;
  checkbox.name = "todo";
  checkbox.className = "mahacheckbox";
  let listitem = document.createElement('li')
  listitem.className = "mahalistitem";
  listitem.setAttribute("style", "list-style-type:none; display:inline;")
  listitem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(textbox.value))
  emptylist.appendChild(listdiv);
  listdiv.appendChild(checkbox);
  listdiv.appendChild(listitem);
}

addbutton.onclick = createlistitem;

//----------------------------------- Remove item from list------------------------------------//
function removeitem() {
  let divimport = document.getElementsByClassName('mahadiv');
  let checkboxcollection = document.getElementsByClassName('mahacheckbox');
  let entryremovaltext = document.createElement("p");
  for (entry = 0; entry < divimport.length; entry++) {
    if (checkboxcollection[entry].checked) { //[i], or [entry] or [z] selects the entry in the array. It can basically be anything
      divimport[entry].remove(); //removes the selected entry
      document.body.appendChild(entryremovaltext);
      entryremovaltext.innerText = "Entry Removed";

      function entryremovaltextimeout() {
        entryremovaltext.remove();
      }
      setTimeout(entryremovaltextimeout, 1000);
    }
  }
}

removebutton.onclick = removeitem;
```

Comment: Hi, I noticed you aren't declaring the variable entry properly. Should be var entry = 0 or let entry = 0. Not sure if that relates to the issue.

Comment: @user3647971 I've been testing out the code. The problem seems to be that for some checkboxes, it doesn't think the checkbox is checked. The variable declaration isn't the problem.

Comment: You could try to console.log(entry) inside the if statement to see does it correspond to what is really checked

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have to delete after the iteration. Otherwise, the indexes could get messed up. *I think.* But I do know that processing the deletion afterwards works.
Your function should look like this:

```
function removeitem (){ 
    let divimport = document.getElementsByClassName('mahadiv');
    let checkboxcollection = document.getElementsByClassName ('mahacheckbox');
    let entryremovaltext = document.createElement("p");
    let ripEntry = [];
    for (entry = 0; entry < divimport.length; entry++){
        if (checkboxcollection[entry].checked) {
            ripEntry.push(divimport[entry]);
            document.body.appendChild(entryremovaltext); 
            entryremovaltext.innerText = "Entry Removed";
            function entryremovaltextimeout (){
                entryremovaltext.remove();
            }
            setTimeout (entryremovaltextimeout,1000);
        }
   }
   ripEntry.forEach((i) => {
       i.remove();
   });
}
```

Comment: And how would indexes get messed up or array internal pointers get messed up when you loop with for?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. That's why I said I think. The difference is that I used a for each and he used a for loop with a counter as the index. The index might get messed up because he's indexing as he's deleting. If anyone can provide a better or more accurate explanation, please do!